# How can I run an entire Python3 file from another Python3 file?

Tags: python

I have 2 .py files: test.py and test2.py

test.py:

```
import test2
print("This is test.py")
```

test2.py:

```
print("This is test2.py")
```

When I run test.py, I get:

```
This is test.py
```

How can I print "This is test2.py" by running test2.py from test.py?

Solution found:

test.py:

```
print("This is test.py")
exec(open("test2.py").read())
```

test2.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This is test2.py")
```

Output:

```
This is test.py
This is test2.py
```

Comment: 1) Yes 2) If you want to use this code in the future and maintain it, you should really refactor it, because else you will get headaches maintaining it

Comment: Something like [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might help with this.

Comment: `import` does exactly what you want.

Comment: @tripleee You can't import a Jupyter notebook file like that. They are formatted in JSON.

Comment: The OP specifically asks about a Python file. Perhaps they should clarify what exactly they mean.

Comment: @tripleee Python3 files are how they are called when creating one in Jupyter. They are also specifying Jupyter in the question. But yes, it would've been clearer if they'd specified the question was about using code from an .ipynb file or not.

Comment: I'm not talking about importing from Jupyter necessarily. I've copied the code to a .py file in VSCode, and I'm trying to use it from another .py file. I'm fine with either of those, but no, importing doesn't do exactly what I want. I'm not trying to run a method from a .py file, I'm trying to run THE .py file.

Comment: That's what `import` does...?

Comment: @KiiVoZin Importing a Python file runs that whole file. Please update your question to include this information and what you are trying to run/what variables you want to access from that file.

Comment: Use `subprocess` to run `python someOtherFile.py` maybe?

Comment: Changed the question. Just importing doesn't run test2, and I'm new to python in general, so I'm sorry if I look dumb.

Comment: @KiiVoZin works as expected. How are you trying to run this file?

Comment: @KiiVoZin there's probably something you are missing. Importing a python file does exactly that - runs the Python file. If you placed the code you expect to run in an `if` statement, that would the reason for it not to execute (for instance `if __name__ == "__main__"` is not met during import - so just place the print outside that `if`)

Comment: @Guy The code I provided at the top was the entire code. No if statements, no nothing. Just what I put. And it didn't work.

Comment: @Guy So ok... In Visual Studio Code, your method works when I run "python test.py". But not when I use the run button on Visual Studio Code. How do you suppose I should change the question?

Comment: @KiiVoZin that's a different question then. What is "doesn't work"? is there an error? what is the behavior? it's a little hard to understand

Comment: @Guy It works when I run "python test.py" on terminal, but not when I run from VSCode run button. My last comment was sort of an apology since you were right all along. Though I did believe what you said worked, I just couldn't get it to work. Now I did, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec(open("main2.py").read())
```

Source: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-run-another-python-script/

Comment: Using `exec` is a serious security risk, and in general running subprocesses is not encouraged and has lots of considerations (e.g. what do to, and how to monitor child process end, how to handle or even receive the errors, what happens when main process crash - you get leaky process etc.)

Comment: He asked how, and gave him answer :/ . I think you should write your own answer, and explain to him why it is a bad idea to have subprocesses. I'm not that much experienced.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are many ways to do, but I think that subproccess will help you:

`subprocess.run(["python", "path/to/test2.py"])`

This will execute a shell command to open python and then tell him(python) to open and execute test2.py.
Here is the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I believe this works too, but I haven't tried it. Thanks!

Comment: Not my downvote, but running Python as a subprocess of itself is dubious advice unless you specifically require the isolation you get from running a separate process (such as separate control over signals etc).

Comment: if they want to "run" the file - just need to import it (unless there are considerations to separate the memory space)

Comment: I agree with @tripleee - invoking subprocesses has a lot of issues, and a lot of care needs to be taken when doing so

Comment: @MarkSetchell for some reason my comment was not sent (I did the downvote). As a veteran software engineer - I provided the reasoning for it to discourage people from using this method.

Comment: @Guy Thank you for taking the time to clarify. I have noticed my comments mysteriously sometimes disappear too. I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with subprocess, nor why it is any worse to run a Python subprocess than running a `bash` script or ELF binary. I don't know how you'd pass parameters or do parallel/background execution either if using `import`.

Comment: Python's built in `multithreading` and `multiprocessing` packages give you much more detailed control over parallelization than spawning off a separate process. Granted, there _are_ situations where that's precisely what you want, but it should probably not be the usual recommendation for how to run Python code when you are already running Python.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you too for taking the time to clarify and edify.

Comment: @MarkSetchell exactly as tripleee said. To elaborate a little - managing subprocesses isn't easy and even when using the standard lib, you need to take care. In this instance, the OP simply wants to run Python code, where he's already within a Python process. There's no reason considering the cons (security, leakage, resources, time, termination etc.) to invoke a subprocess.

Comment: Dear @MarkSetchell, I just proposed an idea, I don't know the exact case of the main problem, reader can google solutions and pick one of them that fits his case. These answers will be used by too many people later. And also i did not down vote, thank you all.